# error: cannot find module 'typescript' ionic

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am new at ionic framework while trying to build the app using "ionic serve" I am facing `error: cannot find module 'typescript'`.
 I have installed the same using `npm install -g typescript`.
Still facing the same issue. What am I missing?

Comment: Just to be sure, does typescript appear in both your package.json file and your node_modules folder?

Comment: Yes it does have

Comment: What version of Ionic and TypeScript are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Problem occurs when you install a new cordova plugin and then directly running. To resolve do the following.

1. Delete node_modules folder
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm i`

Answer (score 2):

Try install TS locally: `npm install typescript`.